# How do I make UIPickerview adjust to screen size?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have a picker that I have created in my iPhone app, and it runs fine - but the picker is part of an overlay, so some of the values are hard-coded as to how far down and to the left the overlay appears.

So an obvious error occurs when I try and make the comparable iPad version.  I opened the iPad storyboard and set everything up, but naturally when I run it, I have the uipickerview appearing in the middle and to the left of the huge iPad screen, wayyy off where it should be.

Is there any way to make an overlay of a picker automatically center and hug the bottom of the screen, no matter what size the screen is, instead of having the location of it hard-coded?

[image: iPhone view]
[image: iPad view]

Comment: doing this with code or constraints?

Comment: Code, I suppose (not sure what you mean by constraints - I've just started programming iOS apps, so I can get lost pretty easily).

Comment: If you're interested in learning about constraints (or Auto Layout, which can solve the issue your dealing with), check this out:  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/xcode_help-interface_builder/articles/UnderstandingAutolayout.html

Comment: Thanks, rog!  Unfortunately this overlay isn't part of the storyboard layout area, so I can't click it and set an auto layout for it.  I can for every other field that's visible, but the overlay is not visible from the storyboard.

(I have, however, used these constraints for everything else - thank you!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you'd like the picker to rest at the bottom of the view controller's main view (it's parent, I assume) and be as wide as the view.  Try this...

```
CGRect viewFrame = self.view.frame;
CGRect pickerHeight = self.picker.frame.size.height;  // assume you have an outlet called picker
CGRect pickerFrame = CGRectMake(0.0, viewFrame.size.height-pickerHeight,
                         viewFrame.size.width, pickerHeight);
self.picker.frame = pickerFrame;
```